# python selenium error " element is not attached to the page document"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i try this code for a textarea

```
textarea =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector('css selector')
textarea.clear()
textarea.send_key('some_text')
```

but i got this error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

**Can you maybe tell me why this error appaer and what can I do to fix it**

Comment: Please post relevant HTML or url of the web page??

Comment: Is this happening on the sendkey?

Comment: It means the DOM is changing between when you find the element and when you send_key. Perhaps it's on the clear action?